# PDFlib - using ArtBox to store width and height of placed elements

Tags: pdflib

Using PDFlib I'm adding elements to a page. My objective is to somehow retrieve combined height and width of the elements after page is closed with `$p->end_page_ext("");`.

I know combined height of elements added to that page.

**Question**. Is it possible to use PDF's `ArtBox` to somehow store these dimensions and later retrieve them?

I'm **not** interested in page's height or width - only the space that added elements occupy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with PDFlib you can also add the ArtBox to a page. (use option "`ArtBox {llx lly urx ury}`" within the `begin_page_ext/end_page_ext()` option list.

Afterwards you can retrieve this values from the PDF. For example when using the pCOS interface (it's part of PDFlib+PDI, PLOP, or TET). You find a code sample for the MediaBox in the pCOS Cookbook: https://www.pdflib.com/pcos-cookbook/pages/page_size/

To retrieve the ArtBox you just need to use the pCOS paths:

```php
           // $pageno is the 0 based index of the pages. First page is 0
           if ($p->pcos_get_number($doc, "type:pages[" . $pageno . "]/ArtBox") == 5)
            {
                $llx = sprintf("%.2f", $p->pcos_get_number($doc, "pages[" . $pageno . "]/ArtBox[0]"));
                $lly = sprintf("%.2f", $p->pcos_get_number($doc, "pages[" . $pageno . "]/ArtBox[1]"));
                $urx = sprintf("%.2f", $p->pcos_get_number($doc, "pages[" . $pageno . "]/ArtBox[2]"));
                $ury = sprintf("%.2f", $p->pcos_get_number($doc, "pages[" . $pageno . "]/ArtBox[3]"));

            }
```